# Custom transformation function throwing error.

Tags: kentico

This is my transformation function call:

```
<p><%# MyFunctions.getDocumentCategory(Eval("DocumentID"))%></p>
```

This is the function:

```
public static string getDocumentCategory(int documentID)
{

    string category;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Get document categories 
    var ds = CategoryInfoProvider.GetDocumentCategories(documentID, "CategoryEnabled = 1", null);
    // Check whether exists at least one category
    if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(ds))
    {

        // Loop thru all categories
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(dr["CategoryDisplayName"]) + ",");
        }
    }
    string content = sb.ToString();

    category = content.Split(',')[0];

    return category;
}
}
```

This is the error:

```
MyFunctions.getDocumentCategory(int) has some invalid arguments.
```

I've tried an alternate form of the function that accepts strings rather than ints but it throws the same error. I've verified that the `Eval("DocumentID")` works correctly when placed by itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eval returns an `object`. You either need to convert it to an `int`, or change the function to accept an `object`, and convert that `object` to an `int`.

```
<p><%# MyFunctions.getDocumentCategory( Convert.ToInt32( Eval("DocumentID") ) )%></p>
```

OR

```
public static string getDocumentCategory(object document)
{
     int documentID = Convert.ToInt32( document );

     etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Doozer for the nice explanation and example.

The second approach - to accept the object and make the conversion inside your custom function - may be better to keep the transformation code cleaner. The result is equal.

Just to add a little bit - you can use Kentico's *ValidationHelper* for conversions, for example:

transformation:

```
<%# MyFunctions.getDocumentCategory(Eval("DocumentID"))%>
```

code:

```
public static string getDocumentCategory(object docID)
{
   int documentID = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(docID, 0); //0 is the default value
   ...
```